# Jsch X11 Forwarding using an android application built on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ssh, remote-access, x11-forwarding

I've successfully set up an android application that remotely accesses a computer using the Jsch library and sends controls. I want to ssh into the computers camera and use x11 forwarding to display it onto the application. I am using android studio to develop the application and have found the feature 'video view'. however. I know you can link it to youtube videos but I'm unclear on how to link the x11 forwarded command to the video view feature. Any help or advice would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X11 forwarding allows a remote X11 client to communicate with a local X11 server. It is not a video stream. Android does not have an X11 server built-in.

You do not need X11 in order to access `/dev/video0`. If you want to forward a video camera, I would suggest you take one of the existing programs that can already [stream video](https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Streaming-V4L) and forward that. For example, if VLC is installed remotely,

```
vlc -I dummy \
    --sout '#transcode{vcodec=h264}:std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8080/video.mp4}' \
    v4l2:///dev/video0
```

will cause VLC to act as an HTTP server, encoding the video device as a stream and serving it at path `http://localhost:8080/video.mp4`. If you forward port 8080 with Jsch or any other SSH implementation, you can easily load it by passing a URL using the local port into MediaPlayer or ExoPlayer or whatever you will use for playback.

Comment: thanks so much for such a helpful response! Just a quick question would i ahve to use SFTP to access the file? And also is the URL you pass into the media player of the format http://localhost:8080/video.mp4 just for clarification?

Comment: @Liz No, sftp is too simple and cannot transfer a steam like this.

Comment: Great so just for clarification this is the java script to read this http server after setting up a new Jsch session :  camsession.setPortForwardingR(8030, "192.168.0.217",23);

            camsession.connect();

            ChannelShell CamChannel = (ChannelShell) camsession.openChannel("shell");
             CamChannel.connect();

             vidView.setVideoPath("http://localhost:8030/video.mp4");
             vidView.start();

Comment: @Liz Not quite, more like `int port = setPortForwardingL(0, "127.0.0.1", 8080)` and `setVideoPath(String.format("http://localhost:%d/video.mp4", port))`.